# Get username displayed as top menu in my web app

Tags: php, html

am trying to get the username of logged in user to be display as a link in the top menu. here is the code I have used:

```
<li><a href="#">$user->Username</a><li>
```

The `$User` is an instance of a class user that contains all information about the user. If I use it somewhere else in the web it works.

Comment: Do this, `<li><a href="#"><?php echo $user->Username; ?></a><li>`

Comment: Thanks. I have tried that but it displays Username; ?> instead

Answer (score 1):

You have to print the value by `echo` command:

```
<li>
    <a href="#">
        <?php echo $user->Username; ?>
    </a>
<li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the foll snippet

```
<?php   print $user->Username; ?>
```

You forgot to use the php tags.

Comment: It is inside php tags but it returns Username;?>. It kind of don't get the username

Answer (score 0):

make sure you use the `<?Php ?>` tag.

example `<li><a href="#"><?Php  echo $user->Username; ?></a><li>`

and also you must use `echo` keyword to display the returned value from object.

Comment: It still gives me the same result

Comment: Sure, send me your email address.

Comment: donnie@donniegallocanta.com